# File.WriteAllBytes causes error "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I have a standard SOAP webservice with a WebMethod which accepts a byte array and then performs a

```
[WebMethod(true)]
WriteFile(byte[] Data, string FilePath)
{

    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, Data);
}
```

If this process is passed a large file, e.g. 2 meg it is bombing out with the following error message:

> Insufficient system resources exist to
>   complete the requested service

Looking at the stack trace i'm getting:

- System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes
- System.IO.FileStream.Write
- System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore
- System.IO.__Error.WinIOError
- System.IO.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete therequested service

I've tried all the obvious things such as setting the maxrequestlength and executing timeout to more realistic settings:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="409600" executionTimeout="900"/>
```

It still seems to fail over with the above. If you send a smaller file it saves to disk fine.. So it's either file size or time that's the issue.

Does anyone know of anything else i can do to sort this out?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 4):

I know you are not reaching this size of file but also be aware that File.WriteAllBytes has a limit of 64mb when writing to network paths - see this [connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=486256)

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try their suggested workaround and get back to you..

string path = "\\server\share\myfile.pdf";
string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName() + "." + Path.GetExtension(path);
File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, file);
File.Move(tempPath, path);

 As i'd love to be able to get the answer to this issue. :-)

Dave

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving a similar error message when using File.WriteAllBytes and changed my code to use a FileStream as in the example below. Based on the comments of others, my guess is that FileStream has a smaller memory impact.

```
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This worked great with the exception that I had to use a `MemoryStream` to first read the source `byte[]` array and then pipe it out in chunks. Followed [this chunking example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468420/175679), using a `MemoryStream` source. In my case, IIS throws this `IOException` when writing to a network share with 20MB+ files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that this could be due to the maxRequestLength. The code is in the middle of FileStream.Write, so long past any question of receiving data. Confirm this by looking at Data.Length in the debugger.

Why do you have WebMethod(true)? Try just [WebMethod] and see what happens.

Comment: Hi,

Yes i've confirmed the server is receiving the data ok. I pass in a check sum in the actual live version, to confirm the received bytes are the same as the bytes past in by the client. I'll try the webMethod suggestion and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: BTW... Just using [webmethod] didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>A maxRequestLength of 409600 will limit the data size to about 400Kb, so a 2Mb file will greatly exceed this.</strike>

The folks over at [GuidanceShare](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/Web_Services_(ASMX_1.1)_Performance_Guidelines_-_Bulk_Data_Transfer) discuss this kind of situation well. In a nutshell:

- If necessary increase the maxRequestLength, as you've discussed.
- Consider implementing streaming. In .NET 1.1, use a class that implements IList as the data transfer object, and set `HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput=false;` in the client-side code. .NET will automatically send the elements of the list one-by-one, so each element of the list might be a 1K buffer of bytes.
- If you can use .NET 2 or above, consider WCF. This implements streaming automatically for HTTP bindings.

---

Well, that's a red herring then! Thanks for the comments, seems that I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi. Looking at MSDN it says that the default is 4096 (4MB)... It says it's in kilobytes.. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… Is it wrong?

Comment: Also it works fine on development and our testing environment, which is very odd!

Comment: MaxRequestLength is in kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

WriteAllBytes loads the entire file into RAM before writing it to disk. You're running out of memory.